# Laravel Cashier Single Charge does it is suitable for this task

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I want to charge the customer 1 euro whenever he wants to do the calculations offered in my system. Every time the customer wants to perform the calculations again, he will have to pay 1 euro again. Would a Laravel Cashier single charge be suitable for such a task or I should choose a simple Stripe SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the Cashier package.

First, the user should set up a payment method.

```php
return view('update-payment-method', [
    'intent' => $user->createSetupIntent()
]);
```

And then in your view:

```js
<input id="card-holder-name" type="text">

<!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
<div id="card-element"></div>

<button id="card-button" data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
    Update Payment Method
</button>
```

Then, you can charge the user every time you want to make a calculation.

```php
// The amount is in cents. 100 = 1 euro
$stripeCharge = $user->charge(
  100, $user->defaultPaymentMethod()
);
```

[You can view the docs for more details.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#payment-methods-for-subscriptions)